# Help with PayPal Payflow Pro on Magento 2.3.4

Tags: magento2, paypal-payflow-pro

I am having the same exact issue as described here:
[Nothing Happens When Paying With PayPal Payflow](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139179/nothing-happens-when-paying-with-paypal-payflow/140741)

In fact, my /var/log/payment.log file looks identical to the one in that post:

```
[2020-02-02 03:53:51] main.DEBUG: array (
  'request' =>
  array (
    'user' => '****',
    'vendor' => 'MYVENDORID',
    'partner' => 'PayPal',
    'pwd' => '****',
    'verbosity' => 'HIGH',
    'BUTTONSOURCE' => 'Magento_Cart_Community',
    'tender' => 'C',
    'trxtype' => 'A',
    'amt' => 0,
    'currency' => 'USD',
    'createsecuretoken' => 'Y',
    'securetokenid' => 'L5dVE9KHJWYeI7XmosYItMbkciK3R5VS',
    'returnurl' => 'https://www.flytrapcare.com/store/paypal/transparent/response/',
    'errorurl' => 'https://www.flytrapcare.com/store/paypal/transparent/response/',
    'cancelurl' => 'https://www.flytrapcare.com/store/paypal/transparent/response/',
    'disablereceipt' => 'TRUE',
    'silenttran' => 'TRUE',
    'firstname' => 'Matt',
    'lastname' => 'Miller',
    'street' => '1290 Greenmeadows Way',
    'city' => 'Ashland',
    'state' => 'OR',
    'zip' => '97520',
    'country' => 'US',
    'email' => 'matt@flytrapcare.com',
    'shiptofirstname' => 'Matt',
    'shiptolastname' => 'Miller',
    'shiptostreet' => '1290 Greenmeadows Way',
    'shiptocity' => 'Ashland',
    'shiptostate' => 'OR',
    'shiptozip' => '97520',
    'shiptocountry' => 'US',
  ),
  'result' =>
  array (
    'result' => '0',
    'securetoken' => '1oAtqrZ6NekKu32BIzag2yArH',
    'securetokenid' => 'L5dVE9KHJWYeI7XmosYItMbkciK3R5VS',
    'respmsg' => 'Approved',
    'result_code' => '0',
  ),
) [] []
```

Looking at the one answer from the person who posed the question, I can see that I have done items #1 and #2.  However, I can't figure out how to change the return URLS in PayPal Manager to POST.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

How can I change the return URLS in PayPal Manager to always POST?

---

EDIT FOR UPDATE:
I have finally logged into manager.paypal.com and found where to update the return URLs through the instructions found here:
https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/payment/paypal-payflow-pro.html#setting-up-paypal-payflow-pro

However, following step #2, I navigate to the "Service Settings" page in PayPal Manager and all I see is a blank page with no options to update anything.  See the screenshot:
[image: PayPal Manager - Service Settings Page]

Any suggestions for next steps as to where to update the settings for Payflow Pro?

Answer (score 0):

The links to edit the information you require are not present, there should be 3 links on the left, of course you probably already have, but contact Payflow support, they have good telephone support and may have to flip a switch or confirm something to allow you access to the settings page. Hope you have things sorted out.